# Galois representation absolutely irreducible after restricting to open subgroup of finite index

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, topological-groups, galois-representations, p-adic-groups

Let $E$ and $F$ be finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $\phi:\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{E}/E)\to GL_n(F)$ be an absolutely irreducible continuous representation. Assume that the restriction of $\phi$ to any open subgroup of finite index is irreducible. Is the restriction of $\phi$ to any open subgroup of finite index absolutely irreducible?